# SMTP setting in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, administration, central-administration

I want to use my organization SMTP server for sending emails from SharePoint.

I know we have to do certain setting in central admin but i am confused whether i need to install n configure SMTP service on My server also or just by doing configuration in sharepoint central admin i can achieve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check with your IT department. You probably already got an SMTP server that you can use.
Then it is just a question of configuring SharePoint for outgoing mail from Central Administration > System Settings > Configure outgoing mail settings

The whole setup (including if you do not have an SMTP server) are described pretty well on Technet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

If you already have an SMTP service start [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section5).

Comment: Thanks,yes. we already have SMTP server in our organization.can we use IP of SMTP server instead of SMTP server name ?

Comment: Hmm I always just use the DNS. Try it with IP and see if it works? :)

Comment: I think it's best to use the Hostname of the name server. If IT decides to change the IP address, the DNS can still resolve the hostname to the correct IP addres.

Comment: Try to use the DNS name of the SMTP service, it will help in the long run. Take note that it is quite possible that further configuration is needed on the mail server regarding permissions and relay configuration.

Comment: using the IP address should work, but use the host name from DNS if at all possible.